# Объяснить как работает вызов функции f(f(f(3))), где f = lambda n: n * 2 + 1

Tags: python-3.x, функции

```
def f(n):
    return n * 2 + 1
f(f(f(3)))
```

Данная функция возвращает нам в виде ответа число 31, может это и элементарно не могу понять почему 31, заранее спасибо!

Comment: `((3 * 2 + 1) * 2 + 1) * 2 + 1 = 31`

Comment: @slippyk СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вызов функции `f(3)` вернет 7.

`3 * 2 + 1 = 7`

Далее это число станет аргументом для следующей функции `f(7)` и вернет 15.

`7 * 2 + 1 = 15`

И третий вызов `f(15)` вернет 31.

`15 * 2 + 1 = 31`